# Ninject In an assembly

Tags: load, repository, ninject, design-patterns

I have a project called MyProjectReport (assembly).  In this project, I have class called 
MyMainReport.  In this class (I am using the repsoitory pattern in an assembly), I have two Interfaces.  One interface is called IReportRepository1 , and IReportRepository2.  In the MyMainReport, my constructor is as follows:

```
public MyMainReport(IReportRepository1 reportRepository1 , IReportRepository1 reportRepository2 )
    {
        this.reportRepository1 = reportRepository1 ;
        this.reportRepository2 = reportRepository2 ;
    }
```

.
I have a NinjectModule as follows:

```
public class DINinjectServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IReportRepository1 >()
            .To<ReportRepository>();
        Bind<IReportRepository2 >()
               .To<ReportRepository2>();

    }

}
```

.
Normally, the applcation would initialize the kernal in the Global asax.
An example of one in a WCf webService would be as follows:

```
public class Global : NinjectWcfApplication
{

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        return new StandardKernel(new DINinjectServiceModule());
    }

}
```

This way, my repositories would be loaded automatically.
However, since I have an assembly, I do not have a Global.asax file.

I created a class called report selector.  i use the decorator pattern to dynamically load my reports.

```
public class ReportSelector : IReportBuilder
{
    IReportBuilder buildareport;

    public ReportSelector(IReportBuilder buildareport)
    {            
        this.buildareport = buildareport;            
    }   

    public void CreateDocument()
    {
        buildareport.CreateDocument();
    }
}
```

Below is how I would normally call the report builder without using an IOC constructor.

```
IReportBuilder buildrep = new ReportSelector(new MyMainReport.ReportBuilder.MyMainReport());
        BuildReport(buildrep);
```

However, it is looking for me to pass in my repository interfaces.  It is not loading them dynamically.  How do I go about setting this up.  to me, the above decorator call would be similar to my application_start in my Global.asax file.  How would I go about loading my repositories in an assembly/project?

Thanks Remo Gloor!  I figured I needed a factory like the one for the Controller in  MVC.  However, I am not sure how I should go about it.  Most  examples have either an extension, or using a base class like the Controller.  I am writing a web service that will execute a batch process.  Using a Web Service is not my choice for this process, even though I know some people like to use Web services for this.  I have an assembly that creates dynamic PDF's, and will email out these PDF's.  I would like to use the Ninject module to load my repositories like you would in an MVC project.  I am not sure how to accomplish this within a standalone assembly.  Currently, I have the reportselector as stated above, this would be like the startup root of any application.  I have a method in my web service called BuildAllReports which any application can call to consume the service.  Thus, when BuildAllReports is called, the batch process executes.  Can you give me an example of using Ninject in an assembly as mentioned?  Thanks

Comment: Is it java? If it is, you will have better results replacing the **assembly** tag for **java**.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use an IoC container is to configure the kernel and resolve everything necessary to run the application in the application root.

You have already shown the correct way for Web and Wcf projects. In case of executables the application root is the program main method.

Since you haven't told what kind of application you are writing I can't tell you which one applies to you.

For everything that can be resolved at application start you have to create a factory interface in your implementation to get these instances. The implementation of this interface is part of your cointainer configuration in the application root. Such factories are the only place where you should access the kernel.